# Removing manually added DataBindings

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding

If a set of controls on a WinForm have had DataBindings created and attached at runtime, should they be removed when the Form is closed? Or will the GarbageCollecter deal with them?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this one, but I'm going to guess that the garbage collector will deal with them because they will be out of scope once the form closes.  However, since this is a guess, I'm going to wait and see what the real experts say.
Good question, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rest assured the GC will take care of them.